# MongoDB extended json to update objectid

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update ObjectId using [mongodb extended json](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

I am using the below to insert the document.

```js
collection.insertMany([{ parentQueryGroupId: { $oid :
"628fadb4d370987ac789c0cd" } }])
```

So it is storing as is like `parentQueryGroupId: { $oid : "628fadb4d370987ac789c0cd"`.

But as I need it to store as `ObjectId("628fadb4d370987ac789c0cd")`

Is this possible directly through extended JSON? Thing is, the server-side query is generic. So I am sending data from the client-side and then directly passing that id to update. But I need it to be ObjectId instead of an object.

I can loop over in such cases where if there is `$oid` key is present then I can convert it to `ObjectId`, but is this natively supported by Mongoose or MongoDB?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/), there is a difference between `Canonical Mode` and `Relaxed Mode` which one are you using? If you are using the `Relaxed Mode`  try: `collection.insertMany([{ parentQueryGroupId: { Types.ObjectId("628fadb4d370987ac789c0cd") } }])` with something like: `import {Types} from 'mongoose';`

Comment: How do we define these modes in node js?

Comment: I don't know, I don't work with `mongodb extended json`. I suggest you try the option that I wrote and see if it works for you...

Comment: Seems docs are only having that for `bsondump mongodump mongoexport mongoimport` methods and not individiual methods. If it is not supported natively then I found another npm package 'EJSON' through which I can convert extended json to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `EJSON` from `bson` package to convert it to the appropriate format as below.

```js
import { EJSON } from 'bson';

collection.insertMany(EJSON.deserialize([{ parentQueryGroupId: { $oid :
"628fadb4d370987ac789c0cd" } }]))

console.log(EJSON.deserialize([{ parentQueryGroupId: { $oid :
"628fadb4d370987ac789c0cd" } }])) // Outputs similar to: [{ parentQueryGroupId: ObjectId("628fadb4d370987ac789c0cd") }]
```

And it is not having issues if it is not extended json. works well without extended types as well (unless you actually want to store those `$oid` format as is because deserialize will convert them too).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

collection.insertMany([{ parentQueryGroupId: {ObjectId("628fadb4d370987ac789c0cd")} }])
```

Comment: just as a note, in case mongoose is not used, use `ObjectId` from `mongodb` directly (it is re-exported from `bson`)